# Background of block element is clipped by viewport

Tags: html, css

I have html like this:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

And CSS like this:

```
.outer {
    background-color: red;
}

.inner {
    width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 300px;
    border: 3px solid black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u2yzyvu3/

The problem is background of the outer div is clipped by viewport.
Does anyone know why it works this way?

I've found the solution: set **display: table; and width: 100%;** to the outer div. But it looks like a hack. What is wrong with my layout?

Comment: Add `overflow:auto` to .outer or move the width of 1300px to .outer not .inner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width of `.outer` is computed like this [[source](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#blockwidth)]:

> The following constraints must hold among the used values of the other
>   properties:
>
> ```
> margin-left + border-left-width + padding-left + width + padding-right + border-right-width + margin-right = width of containing block
> ```
>
> If `width` is set to `auto`, any other `auto` values become `0` and
>   `width` follows from the resulting equality.

Then, the width of `.outer` will be the width of the [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details).

`.inner` has a width of `1300px`, which may exceed `.outer`'s width, and thus overflow. However, `.outer`'s background applies only to `.outer`, not to its descendants.

There are different approaches to solve this problem:

- Add the background to `.inner` too

  ```css
  .inner {
      background-color: inherit;
  }
  ```

```css
.outer {
  background-color: red;
}
.inner {
  width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 300px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

- Make `.outer` wrap around its contents with `display: table`

  ```css
  .outer {
      display: table;
  }
  ```

```css
.outer {
  background-color: red;
  display: table;
}
.inner {
  width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 300px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

- Make `.outer` wrap around its contents with `display: inline-block` (or `inline-table`)

  ```css
  .outer {
      display: inline-block;
  }
  ```

  However, note that `.outer` will be inline-level. This may be a problem if it is surrounded by other inline elements.

```css
.outer {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
.inner {
  width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 300px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

- Make `.outer` wrap around its contents with `float: left`

  ```css
  .outer {
      float: left;
  }
  ```

  Remember to clear the float, though.

```css
.outer {
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}
.inner {
  width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 300px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<span>a</span>
<span>a</span>
```

- Prevent overflow setting `overflow-x` to anything but `visible`:

  ```css
  .outer {
      overflow: auto;
  }
  ```

```css
.outer {
  background-color: red;
  overflow: auto;
}
.inner {
  width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 300px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to accomplish what I think you are, then try adding the style to the parent element ".outer" as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/jimcamut/0pdrbkcp/

```
.outer {
    background-color: red;
    width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 300px;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

.inner {
    /* You can add additional style to the child element */

}
```

Comment: thx for the replay, but it doesn't fit me, I need 100% width footer with background, and 1300px wrapper for content inside it.

Answer (score 0):

```
.inner {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 300px;
    border: 3px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.outer { width: fit-content; }`, modulo vendor prefixes. Alternatively you can also set that on the `:root` selector for the same effect.